# Перехват нажатий в Android Keyboard

Tags: android, клавиатура

Когда человек нажимает на EditText у него появляется виртульная клавиатура. На ней есть всякие кнопки, кроме букв и цифр, к примеру, кнопка Enter.

Мне надо перехватить или запретить нажатие на эти кнопки.
Кнопки типа "смены языка" или еще хуже - долгое нажатие на кнопку "смены языка" появляется диалоговое окно, где можно попасть в настройки.

Вот так я перехватываю нажатие на Enter

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

На остальные у меня не получается.

Comment: вам нужно запретить ввод определённых символов или переход в настройки?

Comment: Переход в настройки.
А это либо перехватом на нажатие этой кнопки, либо вообще убрать эту кнопку с клавиатуры.

Comment: Мне просто интересно, а зачем запрещать? пользователь все равно найдет способ как сделать. А себе проблем добавите. Какую задачу решаете?

Answer (score 1):

В приложениях экранной клавиатуры нажатие на свои собственные кнопки(будь то настройка, включение/отключение Т9, смена языка) не вызывает событие нажатия на кнопку клавиатуры, т. к. набор этих "дополнительных" кнопок определяет сам разработчик клавиатуры, а не система Андроид. Вы, на пример, можете создать свою виртуальную клавиатуру для использования в вашем приложении, и заставить ее появляться тогда, когда фокус падает на EditText, предварительно отменяя показ стандартной клавиатуры.  
Получить ссылку на View, на который упал фокус можно(не помню на вскидку, как, но можно).

Comment: view.setOnFocusChangeListener(OnFocusChangeListener listener);